# How to scale child views inside linearlayout and make it scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created custom linearlayout with zooming in which i'm adding images using ImageView in a vertical orientation. To scroll between the images i used ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView. My problem is when i scaled the custom linear layout scrollview size is not adjusted and top and bottom of the custom linearlayout gets clipped. I dont know where my logic goes wrong. I failed to find the solution using google. Please find my app in the below link and let me know your suggestion to resolve this.
[SampleApp](https://github.com/Sathish6/PanningZoomingApp)

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Any update?

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT,

I will check and update you today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with `ScrollView` and make images vertical laid on your layout, you need to create `HorizontalScrollView` and `ScrollView` inside `LinearLayout` for each `ImageView`.

And your scale is set to the `LinearLayout`, when one image is scaled, all other images will be scaled in the same time. I think what you need to do is to scale each image. Then you can implement the on each `ImageView`, for example create a 
[ScaleImageView](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/MonoDroidToolkit/ScaleImageView.cs).

And since you want to show a list of `ImageView` in `LinearLayout`, you may code for example like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/sv">
  <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:id="@+id/hsv">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root" />
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Code behind:

```
private List<int> imageList = new List<int> { Resource.Drawable.image1, Resource.Drawable.image2, Resource.Drawable.image3, Resource.Drawable.image4 };
private LinearLayout root;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.root);
    root.SetClipChildren(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, imageList[i]);
        var lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        lp.SetMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);
        lp.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
        ScaleImageView img = new ScaleImageView(this, null);
        img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        img.SetScaleType(ScaleType.Matrix);
        root.AddView(img, i);
    }
}
```

To avoid the conflict between `ScrollView` and `Zoom`, modify the `OnTouchEvent` of `ScaleImageView` like this:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    if (m_GestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e))
    {
        m_PreviousMoveX = (int)e.GetX();
        m_PreviousMoveY = (int)e.GetY();
        return true;
    }

    var touchCount = e.PointerCount;
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Down:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Down:
            {
                if (touchCount >= 2)
                {
                    var distance = this.Distance(e.GetX(0), e.GetX(1), e.GetY(0), e.GetY(1));
                    m_PreviousDistance = distance;
                    m_IsScaling = true;
                    var parent = this.Parent;
                    var scrollview = parent.Parent;
                    scrollview.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    scrollview.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            {
                if (touchCount >= 2 && m_IsScaling)
                {
                    var distance = this.Distance(e.GetX(0), e.GetX(1), e.GetY(0), e.GetY(1));
                    var scale = (distance - m_PreviousDistance) / this.DispDistance();
                    m_PreviousDistance = distance;
                    scale += 1;
                    scale = scale * scale;
                    this.ZoomTo(scale, m_Width / 2, m_Height / 2);
                    this.Cutting();
                }
                else if (!m_IsScaling)
                {
                    var distanceX = m_PreviousMoveX - (int)e.GetX();
                    var distanceY = m_PreviousMoveY - (int)e.GetY();
                    m_PreviousMoveX = (int)e.GetX();
                    m_PreviousMoveY = (int)e.GetY();

                    m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                    this.Cutting();
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Up:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Up:
            {
                if (touchCount <= 1)
                {
                    m_IsScaling = false;
                    var parent = this.Parent;
                    var scrollview = parent.Parent;
                    scrollview.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    scrollview.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not suits for my requirement. I want to scale the entire Linear layout and scroll horizontal and vertical without loss of image in top and bottom. Can you please help me out to resolve this?

Simple example : I want to display my images as like the PDF pages displayed in Adobe reader and need to perform zooming the entire children in linear layout

Comment: @SATHISH, oh...I misunderstood. I tested your code, at first I thought it was the `imgView.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);` issue of `ImageView`, cause the `ImageView`'s size doesn't change when scaling. But after I setting it to true, I still get the same issue. Keep working on this now...I'll update my answer when I figured it out.

Comment: @SATHISH, no, still researching, and you?

Comment: No, I too researching

Comment: @SATHISH, I tried to my own demo, still got the same issue. I have no ideas, sorry. If you have some new information, please tell me. Thx.